# Zipping Collections

Tags: python, clojure, zip, sequence

How do you zip two sequences in Clojure? IOW, What is the Clojure equivalent of Python `zip(a, b)`?

EDIT:

I know how to define such a function. I was just wondering whether standard library provides such a function already. (I would be *very* surprised if it doesn't.)

Comment: There is no zip function in core. 'map list' is considered the equivalent idiom.

Comment: the only native function that comes close to zip is 'interleave' which would return (1 4 2 5 3 6).

Comment: I clojure doesn't have a huge standart library like python. I'm sure it will grow but I don't think clojure should provied a to big standard library. A library that is to big is just as bad as a to small one. (I'm not saying this function should not be in the standard library it was just a general note.)

Comment: `(map vector ...)` is considered the equivalent idiom. You almost never need `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily define function like Python's zip:

```
(defn zip
  [& colls]
  (apply map vector colls))
```

In case of `(zip a b)`, this becomes `(map vector a b)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want the input to be lists you can define a zip function like this

```
(defn zip [m] (apply map list m))
```

and call it like this

```
(zip '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
```

this call produces `((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))`

Answer (score 0):

Is this is close enough?

```
(seq (zipmap [1 2 3] [4 5 6]))
;=> ([3 6] [2 5] [1 4])
```

Comment: Not quite: `(seq (zipmap [1 2 1] [3 4 5]))` => `([2 4] [1 5])`.